# Почему не работает .remove()?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Есть меню, и в него добавляется с помощью скрипта один элемент, и удаляется ненужный.

С добавлением элемента проблем нет, а вот с удалением возникли трудности.

Меню с вордпресса горизонтальное, я добавил страницу, и он добавляет пункт со ссылкой на страницу, я убрал заголовок, но все равно меню слегка съехало. Как создать страницу без добавления в меню, я не знаю, вернее известные мне способы не устраивают, поэтому хочу скриптом убрать.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
//удаляем "ненужное"(не работает)
$(".page_item page-item-716").remove();

//добавляем первый пункт в блок ul
$('<li><a href="#">Добавили скриптом</a></li>').prependTo('.menu > ul');
});

</script>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Добавили скриптом</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#" title="р1">р1</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="#" title="р2">р2</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-89"><a href="#" title="р3">р3</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-91"><a href="#" title="р4">р4</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-716"><a href="#" title="">вот этот пункт вместе с ли надо вообще удалить, но не получается </a></li>
</ul></div>
```

**UPD**

remove() -- вполне себе работает. думаю проблема в названии класса с пробелом, как же обойти это?(убрать пробел -- походу не вариант)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(".page_item page-item-716").remove();

//исправить на:

    $(".page_item.page-item-716").remove();
```

в html в class="class1 class2", означает что данный элемент принадлежит двум классам для того чтоб выбрать элемент в jQuery используя оба класса вам нужно пользоваться такими же селекторами как в css

Comment: блин. спасибо. я чуть сам покопался и нашел, что  запись

$(".page-item-716").remove(); --работает

проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

А еще проще прописать в css .page_item .page-item-716 {display:none}, зачем скриптом это делать?

Comment: тоже вариант... хорошая идея, на самом деле, так как мало скрипты у кого то будут выключены.)

спасибо тебе тоже)

Answer (score 0):

а почему не удалить этот пункт меню в самом wordpress?

Comment: это страница с банера, интерфейс должен быть сохранен, но при добавлении страницы, он автоматом кидает его в меню.

редактировать это меню нельзя средствами админки вордпресса, но зато я знаю есть способ, включить это редактирование через functions.php, но я как то включил, и вордпресс стал работать крайне нестабильно, вылитал сам сайт и админка вместе с ней.

пока острой необходимости(пунк всего один, сделано быстро) в решении данного вопроса другими путями -- не стоит. встанет буду решать по другому. пока так -- "на скотче".))

Comment: на странице редактирования меню есть пункт "Автоматически добавлять новые страницы верхнего уровня", галочка стоит?

Comment: нету.нигде нет. в панели редактирования меню, там вообще верхнее меню(ну это у меня оно верхнее, а так оно главное), его редактировать нельзя. описанных вами опция я в админке нигде не встречал. WordPress 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

У вас опечатка `$(".page_item .page-item-716").remove();`

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что подобный ответ уже был дан... ещё в 2011 году. Не стоит дублировать имеющиеся ответы, особенно в таких старых вопросах.